# How to instantly set states to pass parameters in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, state

**Problem**

I'm creating an app in react native, and currently have a problem where I need to set the states of parameters that get passed into the screen when it first loads. I need to set these states because the parameters won't work inside functions, and just give me an error, saying can't find variable 'parameters'. I don't know how to instantly set states, so the solution I am using is to have a button that sets all of the states when it is pressed, but this is very annoying for the user. How can I instantly set states when the screen loads?

**Code**

```
//passing in parameters
render() {

const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;

return (
  <View style={{ flex: 10000, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}}>
  <View style={styles.button}>
  //Button that needs to be pressed to load the states.
  <Button onPress={() =>{
    this.setState({passKey: params.postKey})
    this.setState({passUserID: params.userID})
    this.setState({passContent: params.postContent})
    this.setState({firebaseItems:''});
    this.setState({passID: expoID});
    this.setState({passNameID: params.passNameID});
    this.setState({fontLoaded:true});
  }}
    title="Press to load"
    color="#ff0037"
  />
```

Comment: We have no idea what you're talking about.  Please provide the existing code you want to modify and clarify what you mean by "instantly" and "set a bunch of states", and explain what you've tried that has not worked.

Comment: @JimGarrison sorry about that. I edited it now. Is there anything else I should change?

Comment: This is javascript, not Java.

Comment: @JimGarrison when do I call it java?

Comment: When you tagged it.  I changed the tag to Javascript

Comment: @JimGarrison oh, whoops. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating `constructor()` function and set your `state` with the `params` when the screen loads.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { params } = props.navigation.state;

    this.state = {
        passKey: params.postKey,
        passUserID: params.userID,
        passContent: params.postContent,
        firebaseItems: '',
        passID: params.expoID,
        passNameID: params.passNameID,
        fontLoaded: true
    };
}
```

learn more about [constructor](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor)